# AngularJs event $stateChangeStart not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying  to implement a route based security for users and the `stateChangeStart` doesn't fire, this is my code :

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
      console.log('$stateChangeStart to '+toState.to+'- fired when the transition begins. toState,toParams : \n',toState, toParams);
   });

}]);
```

So whenever I change the route, and jump from one link/controller to another, nothing happens, however when I add a console log inside individual controllers I do see the console log statements.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I debug this, I'm not very experience person in angular

**Update**

I guess I'm using `ngRoute` and not `ui-router`

Is there something equivalent for `ngRoute` that I get the state change on a root scope. Migrating to ui-router seems a big change to do at this point for this purpose

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using ui-router or ngRoute?

Comment: @charlietfl yeah I use `ngRoute` d'oh, is there something equivalent to this for `ngRoute`

Comment: yes, `$routeChange...` ... but this could easily be looked up in the docs also

Comment: @charlietfl yes it could, but if you visit https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute for instance on the right side of the scrolling content I couldn't navigate to that info. But 'easily' is a matter of prospective, you obviously know your way around this, I've just started with angular recently hopefully I ll get to your level sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have differents events from the $route provider : $routeChangeStart, $routeChangeSuccess, $routeChangeError

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    // TODO
});
```

The doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: the lead in was simple for this to be turned into an answer from the comments... at least make it a complete answer with proper sentences